# Have types always get saved with a discriminator without applying [BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)] attribute to each class

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

It is possible to force the MongoDB.Driver to save a discriminator for a specific type by applying the `[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]` attribute.

For example:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Resulting in this json:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3caf1bed2891065c972547"),
    "_t" : "MyClass"
}
```

**Now my question:**
Is it possible to configure the MongoDB.Driver to always save the Discriminator for each type without explicitly applying the `[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]` attribute on each class?

**Edit:**
One possibility would be to derive all entities from a base class which has the `[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]` attribute set. But I would rather prefer not to do this, to avoid having my entities to know too much about the persistence mechanism used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I came up with is creating and registering a custom `ClassMapConvention` ([MongoDB Conventions](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/)).

First we are creating a `ConventionPack` and adding our `ClassMapConvention` to it:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.AddClassMapConvention("AlwaysApplyDiscriminator", m => m.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true));
```

After creating the `ConventionPack` we just have to register it to the `ConventionRegistry` like this:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("CustomConventions", pack, t => true);
```

**Note**
The convention must be registered before any call to the MongoDB Api.

---

Now every object that gets saved to the DB, gets saved with an additional Type *_t* attribute (without the need of explicitly adding the `[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]` attribute on class level):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3caf1bed2891065c972547"),
    "_t" : "MyClass"
}
```